# あわれめ? (“Greetings”)?

Tags: archaic-language

Can あわれむ be used as the Sanskrit “hare”? My dictionary gives “enjoy the beauty of” as an obsolete definition. However, compassion, mercy, and sympathize are also listed, so it’s not clear to me. Most uses of this word may be more polar from what I understand.

I suppose the title of this question, awareme, would be the greeting form, although I have yet to see this in Japanese.

Comment: I know the only word[「ハレー・クリシュナ」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%8A-117566): "Hare Kṛṣṇa". And it is hard for me to relate to 哀れむ in Japanese.

Comment: Yes, I think both words have the same etymology.

Comment: What do you mean by "greeting form"?

Comment: If used in the imperative I imagine it would be telling someone to perform the verb. Similar to English “have a good day” (It’s one of the ways the Hare Krishnans use the word if you have ever listen to them). I guess my question is how archaic is the “enjoy the beauty of” definition of aware? Is this word in general in common use?

Comment: @Ragaroni, I'm not sure you're using the word "etymology" correctly.  As described in the first full paragraph under the "Mantra" section [here at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hare_Krishna_(mantra)#Mantra), _Hare_ likely derives as either the vocative of _Hari_, another name of Vishnu, or the vocative of _Harā_, another name of Rādhā.  Meanwhile, あわれめ is derived as the imperative conjugation of verb あわれむ.  In other words, totally unrelated, and decided not sharing the same etymology.

Comment: @Eirikr You may be right, I've forgotten what book I read that said that there was an etymological connection between those terms.